# Return a google JsonElement in a rest controller

Tags: java, json, rest

My Rest controller contains a method returning a google JsonElement. My method looks like this:

```
 @GetMapping(path = "/device/{id}")
 JsonElement getDevicesConfigs(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    JsonElement driverConfigParams = halBroker.getDriverConfigParams(id);
    return driverConfigParams;
 }
```

When I try to access the url with a valid path variable  (http://localhost:9100/device/milestone), I'm getting this error:

[image]

Can anybody tell me what this error means knowing that the object of type JsonElement returned by the method is a valid json schema.

Answer (score 0):

```
@GetMapping(path = "/device/{id}")
@ResponseBody JsonElement getDevicesConfigs(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    JsonElement driverConfigParams = halBroker.getDriverConfigParams(id);
    return driverConfigParams;
 }
```

Try this. You are missing @ResponseBody annotation it will automatically serialize the returned object into JSON